# Generating a PE Image from MSIL

Tags: c#, .net, executable, cil, portable-executable

I am aware that this question may have been asked before in 90% of itself, but my situation/requirements are somewhat unique. I have made a program that spits out MSIL and now I want put it all into an EXE. I have seen lots of people do the opposite and disassemble the CIL, but I want to make an assembler.

I know the structure of the Portable Executable and have done a lot with PEs in native code but I am struggling to get to grips with the .NET framework. From the native side of things, I realise that the mnemonics in Assembler have equivalent opcodes, but the .NET framework is apparently just written inside the PE and compiled.

I do understand this concept, but I don't know how its done. So my question: how would I go about writing an assembler for MSIL?

I understand it is a complex question but I am struggling with this and it is the final hurdle to my programming language. Built the UI and custom controls, lexer, parser, semantic analysis and now I'm struggling with this. The final step

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the .Net Framework supported languages are built atop the CLR (Common Language Runtime). I don't think the output files are true PE, but must be run via the CLR. similar to Java bytecode running in the Java Runtime. This is what makes programs written using the .Net Framework language and platform agnostic. And they are now working on it being OS agnostic as well (.Net Core).

Comment: Did you have a look at [ECMA 335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), the Common Language 
Infrastructure spec? It should explain how a .Net PE file looks like.

Comment: I recommend you the book .NET IL Assembler by Serge Lidin, it explains every "bit" in a .net assembly: http://www.apress.com/us/book/9781430267614. Also at least the projects mono.cecil, ikvm.reflection und dnlib (they should be all on github) are able to write .net assemblies, so you could get a look what they do.

Comment: Why is `ilasm` not sufficient?

Comment: Where do I find ilasm. I’ve scoured the internet and my disk but can’t find it

Comment: You should have them if you have .NET 4.0 or 2.0 (/ 3.0 / 3.5) installed, for example in:
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ilasm.exe 
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ilasm.exe

Comment: Ilasm was what I was looking for. Thanks for that, makes my life a lot easier.